# update time_out field only on on everylogout to the last inserted id of a user in db?

Tags: php, mysql

so i am storing users time_in and time_out in hours table, when user logs in i insert date and time into the time_in field and the time_out value remains 000:00:00:00 now how do i update the time_out field on logout only on the last inserted id i update the date and time?

no matter how many logouts it should keep updating time time_out only on the last inserted of user id in hours table, but if new login id is entered then it changes to the new one i tried something like this

$dt = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

```
UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']."'
```

fields in the hours table are

```
hours_id
member_id
member_name
team
time_in
time_out
```

i haven't a clue how to achieve the rest. would appreciate your help

ok here is my logout.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
    //Start session
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
}   
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');      
$sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']."'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['LOGIN_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['PASS']);
    unset($_SESSION['TEAM']);   
?>
```

Comment: Do you have an auto increment id field in the DB, you could query for the MAX(id) for that user first.  `SELECT max(id) as LastId FROM hours WHERE member_id = :member_id`  Dont assume the session variables are safe to inject into your sql, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter with the max id of that user entries:

$max = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']."'");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($max);

Then, your original query will be:

UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE hours_id = '".$row[0]."'

Comment: thank you soo much mate im trying but no affect to the time_out field it stays 00:00:00:00

Comment: Check that $dt and $_SESSION['MEMBER_ID'] are defined (not null) before the query declaration

Comment: i tried echoing they do show results in the same way if i do a insert into hours it gets inserted from logout.php but why wont it get update

Comment: the schema is like this 

  `hours_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `team` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `time_in` datetime NOT NULL,
  `time_out` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hours_id`)

Comment: got this error message Erreur de syntaxe près de '' à la ligne 1

Comment: Ok something in the syntax is broken, probably the " character is generating it. Can you show the entire php line where you declare and execute this query?

Comment: the error is stating

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '01:45:50 WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id =' at line 1

Comment: From that error I can see that the problem might be that when parsing the $dt variable in your query the ' character that is enclosing $dt is being lost.

Comment: UPDATE hours SET time_out = '2016-07-30 02:03:24' WHERE member_id IN (SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = 1'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

Comment: Could be there's a ' character after the "member_id = 1" at the end of the query? If so remove it.

Comment: this is the only query mate what could be the error seriously

Comment: mate it was the bracket which was missing now there is an issue with the query

Comment: You can't specify target table 'hours' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Ok then in this case you will have to do it separately. Get the id first then use it. Let me update the answer.

Comment: how would i need to get the id? its confusing me mate :)

Comment: Just edited the answer. Be patient it is not always easy to debug errors and I don't have your database to try and get it work. I only have the info you give to me.

Comment: true my i really appreciate your time and patient with me, well i tried that code but still not updating max hour_id is not echoing anything on screen i tried to echo it

Comment: Sorry my mistake i needed to use mysql_fetch_row. I updated the answer again. Hopefully the last time ;)

Comment: ok it is finally working :)  but only updating time_out for member_id 1 if try to login and logout with different ids its not updating :D

Comment: Excellent. Well that is happening because your $_SESSION['MEMBER_ID'] is not changing correctly when you logout and log in again. Check that

Comment: i tried to echo the r $_SESSION['MEMBER_ID'] it does display different session ids. wonder what else could be the reason that only member_id 1 gets updated

Comment: I think I know, in the where clause of the update it should be hours_id, not member_id. Check my edites answer

Comment: and i am sooo grateful to you for giving me your valuable time and help. appreciate it may god bless you with lots of happiness :)

Comment: Thanks and no problem. Happy to helped you out!